# Looking to form 2 sets of data from a object of arrays - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, math

I am looking for help with the data in a football related app I am building.

Take this as a sample of the object I am dealing with:

```
const squad = {
  goalkeepers: [
    { player1: { score: 10 } },
    { player2: { score: 12 } }
  ],
  defenders: [
    { player3: { score: 3 } },
    { player4: { score: 19 } },
    { player5: { score: 5 } },
    { player6: { score: 21 } },
    { player7: { score: 6 } },
  ],
  midfielders: [
    { player8: { score: 7 } },
    { player9: { score: 1 } },
    { player10: { score: 18 } },
    { player11: { score: 11 } },
    { player12: { score: 8 } },
  ],
  attackers: [
    { player13: { score: 7 } },
    { player14: { score: 2 } },
    { player15: { score: 16 } }
  ]
}
```

There are 15 players here and I want to divide them into two groups:

- A strongest possible outfield team of 11 players based on their **score** value.
- The remaining 4 players are to go on the bench.

The twist here is that there is a minimum and maximum number of players required in each position of the 11 outfield players.

- Goalkeepers: EXACTLY 1.
- Defenders: MIN 3, MAX 5.
- Midfielders: MIN 2, MAX 5.
- Forwards: MIN 1, MAX 3.

For anyone familiar with [Fantasy Premier League](https://fantasy.premierleague.com/help/rules), the rules work the same way:

> Your team can play in any formation providing that 1 goalkeeper, at least 3 defenders and at least 1 forward are selected at all times.

I've tried concatinating the arrays to one large array and sorting them by player score value but I can't work out how to calculate the strongest first 11 players from that point while adhering to the position rules.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With data this small, I think it's simplest to go with brute force.  You can easily calculate all 1365 combinations of 11 of the 15 players, filter out those that don't match the criteria, calculate their scores and take the best one.  If you try this and get stuck, please edit to show your work and explain what is going wrong.

Comment: Step 0 - add goalkeeper with max score, step 1 - add forward with max score, step 2 - add two midfielders with max scores, step 3 - add three defenders with max scores, step 4..11 - add one of remaining players with max score only if his "group" is not full yet.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the suggestions. I found the approach suggested by @bylazy to be the most helpful and solved it this way. If you want to leave an answer with this I will select it as the solution.

Comment: BTW, your input structure is quite odd, and quite challenging to work with.  If you can, instead of `{ player1: { score: 10 } }`, I would suggest something like `{ name: 'player1', score: 10 }`, or even better, a flat list of items like: `{ name: 'player1', score: 10, position: 'goalkeeper' }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a modular approach more intuitive and resilient.

This solution breaks the problem down into first converting your data to a more useful format, then finding all the combination of eleven players, then filtering out those that don't match the rules, then choosing the one with the largest score:

```js
// utility functions
const maximumBy = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, x, i) => fn (x) > fn (a) ? x : a, xs [0] || null)

const choose = (n, xs) =>
  n < 1 || n > xs .length
    ? []
  : n == 1
    ? [...xs .map (x => [x])]
  : [
      ...choose (n - 1, xs .slice (1)) .map (ys => [xs [0], ...ys]),
      ...choose (n , xs .slice (1))
    ]


// helper functions
const simplify = (squad) => 
  Object .entries (squad) .flatMap (
    ([position, vs]) => vs .flatMap (
      (v) => Object.entries (v) .flatMap (([name, s]) => ({position, name, ...s}))
    )
  )

const validate = (rules) => (lineup) => rules .every (({position, min, max}) => {
   const count = lineup .filter (({position: p}) => p == position) .length
   return count >= min && count <= max
})

const totalScore = (lineup) =>
  lineup .reduce ((t, {score}) => t + score, 0)


// main function
const bestLineup = (squad, rules) => 
  maximumBy (totalScore) (choose (11, simplify (squad)) .filter (validate (rules)))


// sample data
const rules = [{position: 'goalkeepers', min: 1, max: 1}, {position: 'defenders', min: 3, max: 5}, {position: 'midfielders', min: 2, max: 5}, {position: 'attackers', min: 1, max: 3}]

const squad = {goalkeepers: [{player1: {score: 10}}, {player2: {score: 12}}], defenders: [{player3: {score: 3}}, {player4: {score: 19}}, {player5: {score: 5}}, {player6: {score: 21}}, {player7: {score: 6}}], midfielders: [{player8: {score: 7}}, {player9: {score: 1}}, {player10: {score: 18}}, {player11: {score: 11}}, {player12: {score: 8}}], attackers: [{player13: {score: 7}}, {player14: {score: 2}}, {player15: {score: 16}}]}


// demo
console .log (bestLineup (squad, rules))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start with two general-purpose utility functions we might use in other projects

- **`maximumBy`** takes a function that converts a value into a comparable one -- in this problem we use it to extract the score -- and return a function that accepts an array of values, runs that function on each and chooses the one with the largest score.  (This version is less efficient than it could be.  I'd rather focus on simplicity at the moment.
- **`choose`** finds all subsets of `n` elements of your array of values.  For instance, `choose (2, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])` returns `[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'd']. ['b', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['c', 'd']]`.

Then we have some helper functions,

- **`simplify`** turns your initial `squad` format into something more tractable:

  ```js
  [
    {name: "player1", position: "goalkeepers", score: 10},
    {name: "player2", position: "goalkeepers", score: 12},
    {name: "player3", position: "defenders", score: 3},
    // ...
    {name: "player15", position: "attackers", score: 16}
  ]
  ```
- **`validate`** takes an array of rules such as

  ```js
  {position: 'defenders', min: 3, max: 5}
  ```

  and returns a function that takes a lineup from the squad and reports whether that lineup obeys all the rules.
- **`totalScore`** takes a lineup and sums up the scores of all the players

Finally, our main function, `bestLineup` accepts a squad and an array of rules, *simplifies* the squad, *chooses* all lineups of eleven players, filters it down to just those which *validate* according to the rules, and chooses the *maximum by* our function that calculates their *total score*.

If you want the output in the same format as the input, we can just call one more helper to undo our `simplify`; let's call it `complexify`:

```js
const complexify = (xs) => 
  xs .reduce (
    (a, {name, position, score}) => (
      (a [position] = a [position] || []), (a [position] .push ({[name]: {score}})), a
    ), {})
```

which will transform an array of the simple format used above back into something like this:

```js
{
    goalkeepers: [
        {player2: {score: 12}}
    ],
    defenders: [
        {player4: {score: 19}},
        {player5: {score: 5}},
        {player6: {score: 21}},
        {player7: {score: 6}}
    ],
    midfielders: [
        {player8: {score: 7}},
        {player10: {score: 18}},
        {player11: {score: 11}},
        {player12: {score: 8}}
    ]
    attackers: [
        {player13: {score: 7}},
        {player15: {score: 16}}
    ],
}
```

But I would only do this if your unusual data format is forced upon you.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. This worked for me. I realise now that my data was in a weird format as you highlighted, so that was complicating matters. Thank you for the solution!